# compile c code on mac for use on iphone?

Tags: iphone, macos, gcc, compiler-construction, cross-compiling

How would I go about setting everything up to cross compile from my OSX 10.6 Macbook pro with xcode to my jailbroken 4th generation iPod touch. I'm mainly aiming to be able to port open source libraries to iphone. I can't seem to find any good/recent articles on cross compiling for iOS 4.

Comment: what cross-compiling? It's standard way to compile source in objective-c on Mac OS X and you're pushing it to iPhone/iPod/iPad...

Comment: You just need XCode and included iOS SDK

Comment: like i mean... compiling the binaries on my mac for use on my iphones terminal

Comment: @Marek Sebera, is that true? i can just open a new c project and set the sdk in info to iphone and it will be iphone only binary?

Comment: yes, that's the way it works. you create XCode project, set target, add libraries and code, and you can push the code into iphone device

Comment: By add libraries what do you mean?

Comment: Isn't it more complicated than suggested answers when linking in libraries which have complex make files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think about it, *all* projects built in XCode are cross-compiled for the iPhone. All you have to do is open an ios project, include your sources and build it.

More specifically, when you have a project in XCode, in the Build Settings tab there is an option for you to specify the architecture to compile - this is automatically set to something like 'armv7' for ios projects.

Comment: this is a great idea!, it seemes to work well until i get to code signing.... lol keep getting this error....

Comment: Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

Comment: also, i looked in the developer folders and found arm-iphone gcc compilers in the bin folders and tried to use them, go tuns of errors

Comment: The code signing is a completely different problem :) To sign an app you need to have a certificate that you have requested from apple using your public/private key pair. Then you will need a provisioning profile for the app you're trying to build. I don't know how to get XCode just to build a library without building an app, sorry :( Try asking it as a new question on stack overflow ;)